# reading a file with a running name from 0 to N

Tags: c++

I have N+1 files in a folder called b0.txt,b1.txt,b2.txt, ....,bN.txt.
I would like to open them inside a loop because for each of them I would like to copy the first 15 characters inside an array.

The code lines I wrote are basically:

```
int main(){

   int N=4; 
   int i;
   char number [15];

   for(i=0; i< N; i++){

             ifstream OpenFile("b%i.txt");

             int l=0;

             while(!OpenFile.eof()) {                     

                 OpenFile >> number [l];
                 l++;
             }
             OpenFile.close();
       }
    }
```

I'm using Dev C++ and when I compile these code lines no errors are shown. However, I'm not able to run the program.

Do you have any tip?

Comment: b%i will be treated as a string as is ... You should do something as std::string s = "b" + i + ".txt" and then use it in filename ..

Comment: btw if you want to read "b4.txt" you should use `<=` in the for loop

Comment: And also if you want to read the first 15 characters from the file .. the while loop condition is wrong ..

Comment: Do . not . use . `while(!file.eof())`

Answer (score 1):

You should build the string name of the file. You might try:

```
 char bufname[64];
 snprintf(bufname, sizeof(bufname), b%i.txt", i);
 ifstream OpenFile(bufname);
```

or use `std::string` or `std::ostringstream` tricks.

Answer (score 1):

The filename `"b%i.txt"` is used explicitly as written, not as a printf-style format specifier.

You can either use `sprintf`, e.g.:

```
char filename[512];
sprintf(filename, "b%i.txt", i);
ifstream OpenFile(filename);
```

or use the C++ `ostringstream`, e.g.:

```
std::ostringstream filename;
filename << "b" << i << ".txt";
ifstream OpenFile(filename.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

"b%i.txt" doesn't put `i` into the string... you can use:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << 'b' << i << ".txt";
if (std::ifstream f(oss.str().c_str()))
    ...f is an open stream - use it here...
else
    std::cerr << "couldn't open file " << oss.str() << '\n';
```

Don't test for `eof` - it doesn't work like that.  Just use [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount):

```
if (OpenFile.read(number, sizeof number) && f.gcount() == sizeof number)
    ...you got the data...
else
    std::cerr << "unable to read 15 characters from " << oss.str() << '\n';
```

(FWIW, `eof` is set after an input operation is concluded or aborted due to hitting `eof`, so it's not false before you attempt input, and it not being set doesn't guarantee the next operation will succeed - how could it if the stream doesn't yet know what you'll try to read?)

Answer (score 0):

Your program does nothing to get the value of `i` into the string that you are sending to `OpenFile()`. You have to create a string with a textual representation of `i` embedded in it, which this code does not do.

Change

```
OpenFile("b%i.txt")
```

to

```
char filename[8];
sprintf(filename, "b%d.txt", i); // Create filename with embedded number
ifstream OpenFile(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream OpenFile("b%i.txt");
```

You're not writing in Batch! Here you can't put number variable using `%name` syntax.

If you're using C++11, I'd recommend to use `std::to_string` and type:

```
ifstream OpenFile("b"+std::to_string(i)+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

for the code line where you are reading the characters in array 
"OpenFile >> number [l];"

the compiler will through the error "segmentation fault" due to array out of bound.

so you have to add condition like this

```
if( l <= 14) // bcz you are starting with l=0
    {
        OpenFile >> number [l];
    }
else
     break;
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the reason for your problem but this is for sure a problem if your program able to run